# htaccess url rewrite - multiple variables

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to rewrite this url: `http://www.sample.com/product_guide&product_name=waht&product_type=dog-clipper`
 to:
`http://www.sample.com/waht/dog-clipper`

I am using this htaccess code:

```
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^product_guide&product_name=(.*)&product_type=(.*)$  
 RewriteRule ^$ %1/%2? [R=301, L]
```

But it doesn't work. Please help me.

Comment: Wait, which do you want your end user to see & use? Typically that would be the `http://www.sample.com/waht/dog-clipper`, and you have your rewrite backwards.

Comment: I want users to see `http://www.sample.com/waht/dog-clipper` and not the dynamic counter part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want users to access `http://www.sample.com/waht/dog-clipper`, you have your rewrites backward.  You need to match that URL and rewrite it to the appropriate query string:

```
RewriteEngine On
# Don't match real existing files so CSS, scripts, images aren't rewritten
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Match the first two groups before / and send them to the query string
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+) product_guide?product_name=$1&product_type=$2 [L]
```

Comment: I can't get it work. I'm using this htaccess tester `http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/`

Comment: @jaysonatic It will work - the htaccess tester just doesn't cannot process the `REQUEST_FILENAME` conditions.  Comment them out when testing and it will work correctly, but add them back in when you put this into production.